# Scheme (DrRacket) - cond statement does not work with recursion

Tags: scheme, racket

I am learning Scheme using DrRacket R5RS.  I thought that I was nailing down the concepts, but I cannot get this simple recursion exercise to work.  I think that it is a bug in DrRacket, but I'm not sure.

Can someone see the problem and, hopefully, explain why my code does not work? I really want to learn this functional language.

This code will produce #T and #F correctly:

```
(define three (lambda (L target1 target2 target3 sum)
    (cond
        ((= target1 0) (three L (car L) (cadr L) (caddr L) 0))
        ((NULL? L) (= (- sum (+ target1 (+ target2 target3))) (+ target1 (+ target2 target3))))  ; sum minus targets = targets
        (else (three (cdr L) target1 target2 target3 (+ sum (car L))))       ; return true if branch returns true
)))
```

When I launch the program with (three '(1 2 3 6) 0 0 0 0), it returns #T since 1+2+3=6. When I launch the program with (three '(1 2 3 5) 0 0 0 0), it returns #F since 1+2+3!=5.

Now, here is the problem. I want to do multi-branch recursion. However, this code returns #T every single time! Since I cannot get it to return #F, I cannot get it to skip to the next branch of my recursion.

```
(define three (lambda (L target1 target2 target3 sum)
    (cond
        ((= target1 0) (three L (car L) (cadr L) (caddr L) 0))
        ((NULL? L) (= (- sum (+ target1 (+ target2 target3))) (+ target1 (+ target2 target3))))  ; sum minus targets = targets
        ((three (cdr L) target1 target2 target3 (+ sum (car L))) #T)       ; return true if branch returns true                  
        (else 'hit_the_bottom)  ; IT NEVER HITS THIS STATEMENT!                  
)))
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Quick answer: replace the last line with `(else #f)` and it'll work. To see _why_, take a look at my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is too complicated, if you only want to check if the sum of the first three numbers in a list equals the fourth number, a simpler non-recursive approach will work better:

```
(define (three lst)
  (= (+ (first lst) (second lst) (third lst))
     (fourth lst)))
```

Other than that, why don't you stick with the first approach? it works for you, and it's not clear what do you mean with "multi-branch recursion", and why is it necessary for the second approach - isn't the first approach "multi-branch"? after all, it's already recursively calling `three` in *two* parts. Regarding the reason why the second approach is always returning `#t` - this line:

```
(else 'hit_the_bottom)
```

... will indeed get executed, but because it's part of a recursive call, it will get returned to this line:

```
((three (cdr L) target1 target2 target3 (+ sum (car L))) #t)
```

And the value `'hit_the_bottom` is `#t`, so the whole procedure will return `#t` in the end. Be aware that in Scheme *everything* that is not `#f` is `#t`, and in this case in particular, `'hit_the_bottom` will be interpreted as `#t`. Just to be clear that the `else` part is really being executed, run this code and you'll see `'hit_the_bottom` printed on the screen exactly once:

```
(define three
  (lambda (L target1 target2 target3 sum)
    (cond ((= target1 0)
           (three L (car L) (cadr L) (caddr L) 0))
          ((null? L)
           (= (- sum (+ target1 target2 target3))
              (+ target1 target2 target3)))
          ((three (cdr L) target1 target2 target3 (+ sum (car L)))
           #t)
          (else (display 'hit_the_bottom) 'hit_the_bottom))))

(three '(1 2 3 6) 0 0 0 0)
=> #t
(three '(1 2 3 5) 0 0 0 0)
=> hit_the_bottom #t
```

Finally, to correct the second approach, replace the last line with `(else #f)` and it'll work as expected.

Comment: You gave me a more efficient alternative. Then, you explained my issue incredibly well so I now fully understand why it happened. In addition, you gave a fix so my application now runs and I can finish the additional parts.  You are amazing. Thank you!